# Convert a price attribute to float

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-attribute

I have made a new attribute called RRP. It has exactly the same settings as the Price attribute. But when I `var_dump` the value inside the attribute it is displaying as a string when I need it to be a float so I can calculate a percentage.

This is what I currently have:

```
$RRP = Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($product->getrrp_price());
```

Which formats the price.

Then I use

```
$rrp_String =  $value = preg_replace('/^\D+/u', '', $RRP);
```

To make it into a string without the £ so I can have an if-statement to check if it is over 0. How could I change this line to convert $RRP into a float instead of a string?

So I want to replace the `$rrp_String` line with something that will convert `$RRP` into a float as then I can use it in the same if-statement as well as when I'm trying to calculate percentages using the RRP

#### Edit

I ended up using:

```
<?php
$RRP = $product->getrrp_price();
$rrp_float = floatval($RRP);
?>
```

Without `$rrp_String =  $value = preg_replace('/^\D+/u', '', $RRP);`

This seemed to have solved the problem

Comment: Why do you need a float in order to see if the value is > 0?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear i don't need it for that reason as the If statement i already have works fine but when it comes to trying to calculate a percentage using the RRP it wont work as it isnt a number

Comment: PHP will convert a string like `'1.5'` to float automatically when needed: `var_dump('1.5' / 2);` outputs `double(0.75)`

Comment: But when i var_dump but rrp attribute ($RRP) it prints out a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure if i'm just misunderstanding your question (sorry if I have) but there is no need to format the price if you're just checking the value.

Just use:

```
$price = $product->getrrp_price();
if ($price > 0) {
    $rrp = Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($price);
}
```

Think you're over-complicating what you're trying to do :-)

You can cast an integer (or resulting string provided it is just numbers) as a float with:

```
(float)$rrp;
```

Comment: Im displaying the Price as well however your last bit of your answer maybe what im looking for. will just check and let you know

Comment: I already have the attribute $RRP which is being pulled from the backend of magento and it is being pulled in as a string, i need to convert it into a float

Comment: In which case I would has it a guess this is a custom attribute that you've added that has its type set to 'text field'. If you look in manage attributes for the rrp_price attribute, and let me know.

Comment: Yea it is a custom attribute i made and th input type in set to Price

Comment: Okay, so following this down, your using $RRP = Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($product->getrrp_price());
Which returns a string, you then regex it to take the £ sign off? If: $product->getrrp_price(); is returning a string, the problems further up the line. It should return an int/double.

Comment: Even when i dont format the price and just grab the attribute in form magento and var_dump it it is still a string?

Comment: Some further progress i added $rrp_float = floatval($rrp_String) and $rrp_float returns float(2) but no digits next to it

Comment: managed to solve in by using this  
<?php $RRP = $product->getrrp_price();
$rrp_float = floatval($RRP);?>

It was the regex that wouldn't let it convert. I have accepted your answer as it pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Glad you solved it, although still odd you're getting a string from a 'price' set attribute.